# Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on null Yii2 //Error al llamar función

Tags: php, login, yii2

estoy tratando de hacer un Login en Yii2 pero, tengo algunos problemas al agregar esta linea:

```
      <?=$form->field($model,'Usuario', ['inputOptions' =>['autofocus' => true]])->textInput(); ?>
```

y aparece esta linea de error **Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on null in yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveField.php**

Así es como tengo el código: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando elimino esa linea todo esta bien

```
    <?=$form->field($model,'Usuario', ['inputOptions' =>['autofocus' => true]])->textInput();
```

evertythings ok.
Soy nueva en Yii2 así que no conozco muchoo, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Welcome to SOes Lissette! This site is spanish only, could you translate your question?

Comment: Yes, of course. thank you so much

Comment: Hola!, mira estaba leyendo y este link aparece mucha informacion sobre login en Yii2: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/864/how-to-login-from-different-tables-in-yii2 ,   espero que te sirva de ayuda!

Comment: Lo revisaré, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debes pasar el $model desde el controlador a la vista principal y desde ahí a las vistas donde las ocupes, con algo como:

En el controlador

```
return $this->render('agregar', ['model'=>$model]);
```

En la vista `agregar.php`

```
...
echo $this->render('_form', ['model'=>$model]);
...
```